# IDE capable of saving to two locations and a SVN repo?

Tags: php, javascript, svn, ide

I’m just wondering if anyone’s come across or could recommend an IDE that’s capable of the following:

Key requirements:

- Save to two locations as a part
  of the normal save operation. (Local or network drive and a web server dev box.)
- Subversion integration (in addition to
  the above).
- Windows based
- Code highlighting (and ideally
  function completion/hinting, etc.)
  for PHP, JavaScript & HTML.
- Ability to switch between multiple
  projects. (And ideally export project
  configuration information.)

Unfortunately, the only IDE that I’ve managed to locate thus far that fits the bill is Dreamweaver CS4, which seems like complete overkill especially when you consider the fact that it’ll only ever be used as a text editor. (i.e.: We'd never touch design mode, etc.)

As such, I’m just wondering/hoping that some of you out there might be aware of a more elegant solution that fits the bill.

---

Update to clarify goal

The key goal is to save to a file server, a web development server (to view changes in real-time) and also to integrate with SVN. I realise this is odd - the rationale being that I'm trying to get the organisation I work for to take some baby steps towards using version control, and this seems the only feasible back door.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of problem you're trying to solve, perhaps there's alternative solutions. The "save to two locations" seems to indicate that you're trying to keep backups automatically, there are good solutions to handle that without changing the tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) with the following plugins:

- [phpeclipse](http://phpeclipse.net)
- [aptana javascript support](http://aptana.com)
- [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

To save my projects in two locations I'm using **[WinSCP](http://winscp.net)** with the feature "Commands" > "**keep remote directory up to date**". There I set my local folder and the remote SSH/FTP folder and WinSCP keeps these folders up to date while I'm working locally on Windows.

You can download Eclipse as a bundle on Yoxos with the plugins I mentioned here: http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start

Comment: Hmm... I like the idea of removing the 'save to two places' requirement with some form of sync.

Comment: Yes it is really cool, I don't have a PHP server installed locally on my Windows machine. I'm working "remotely" on Linux but my environment is Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, saving directly to a web dev server is not a very good idea. Rather, consider using Continous Integration server to publish your code in one shot.

I am personally not aware of any text editors which can save to several locations. However, you can write a post-commit hook to your SVN repository which would copy required files to web dev server.

Comment: It's an internal only web dev server (as opposed to everyone having a web server setup on their local machines). That said, cheers for the Continuous Integration tip - I'll do some digging.

Comment: I agree with Anton. "Saving to SVN" would in essence be performing a commit for every save operation on every file. Not only would this bloat your repository with ten-fold the number of relevant revisions, but each revision would contain one file and wouldn't include comments. Imagine trying to navigate the history!

As an alternative, I would have the web dev box automatically grab the nightly build from SVN (or on demand) and keep your repository up-to-date in the conventional way.

Comment: I wouldn't want every save to go into SVN, only commits as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Studio is a good one.

If you use the command line svn, you can pick any IDE you want and at least it works.

(or tortoise svn on windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount directory with your code located on remote linux sever using Samba and then edit files in your favourite IDE as they are kept locally (this is how I work for the last couple of years).

You can use other software to mount that folder to windows ([WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html), ExpanDrive), but Samba has much much better performance.